# Change:position event for every cell in the paper using joint.js

Tags: javascript, jointjs

By clicking on a blank space of the paper a new cell will be added:

```
paper.on({
    'blank:pointerdblclick': function(event, x, y) {
        var rect = new joint.shapes.app.Standard({
            position: { x: x, y: y },
            size: { width: 100, height: 80 },
        });

        graph.addCell(rect);

        rect.on('change:position', function() {
            paper.fitToContent();
        });
    }
});
```

But as the `change:position` event is set in the `blank:pointerdblclick` event, it just fires for new elements. But it should be set for all cells exisiting for this paper.
So for moving of any cell on the paper the fitToContent()-function should be done...

How do I do that?

P.S.: The standard-element is defined like this:

```
joint.shapes.app.Standard = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend({
    markup: '<rect/><circle class="port-top"/><circle class="port-bottom"/><circle class="port-right"/><circle class="port-left"/><text/>', 
    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
        type: 'app.Standard',
        attrs: {
            ...
        }
    }, joint.shapes.basic.Generic.prototype.defaults)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**graph.getElements()**](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Graph:getElements) and iterate over them setting the handler

```
graph.getElements().forEach(function(element) {
    element.on('change:position', function() {
        paper.fitToContent();
    });
```